# Repeated Measures in SEM

Tags: experiment-design, structural-equation-modeling, group-differences, growth-model, amos

I would have a question about using Structural Equation Modeling for comparing repeated measures results. I have a one DV which has been measured 4 times and corresponds to 4 different experimental conditions (A, B, C, D). The DV was measured on the same scale across the 4 conditions. My question is whether there is a way to model this in SEM. As my variable is not dependent upon time but just a different experimental condition, I guess latent growth would not be appropriate - do you have suggestions about possible alternatives?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use SEM? We don't even know what your research questions are...

Comment: Why don't you just use ANOVA ? A latent growth model has latent variables for the growth factors. I don't see where any latent variable would  fit in to the setup as you have described it.

Comment: It's very easy. You have four variables in your data. You have four variables in your SEM. You can analyze them any way you want to. But as the others say, you'll get almost the same result as if you used ANOVA (although it's slightly more complex, because of things like sphericity).

Comment: I'll depart from the other comments here, and say that I think there *could* be good reasons for analyzing your data with SEM (v. ANOVA). That is, provided you are analyzing a latent variable w/ repeated measures, then it would allow you to test for measurement invariance (which could be substantively interesting in its own right), and would provide you greater statistical power to detect mean differences between your four repeated-measure conditions (v. ANOVA). If this is of interest to you, I can sketch out a more detailed answer w/ some example code later.

Comment: Isn't invariance (in this situation) just another way of looking at sphericity? (Although I agree that I find invariance much easier to think about than sphericity, which would lead me in the direction of SEM.)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Just to provide some more info about my research question, I am looking to test the relationship between a set of IVs on a DV (latent in SEM). The DV has been measured 4 times as the participants were subjected to 4 different conditions. I have already done ANOVA tests to see the group differences but I have been suggested to use SEM to test the relationship between the set of IVs and their impact on the repeated measures DV in different conditions.This is the first time I am using SEM so thank you for all the suggestions that you might have!